# JPA OneToMany and return child id

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm

I have two entity - User and Task in OneToMany relaction. After add task to user i want to return from method an id of this task but it returns null (in database a task has a proper number id).

Method:

```
@RequiredArgsConstructor
class CreateTaskHandler {

private final UserRepository userRepository;
private final TaskContentValidator taskContentValidator;

@Transactional
Either<TaskError, TaskDto> handle(CreateTask command) {
   return userRepository.getByUsername(command.getUsername())
            .map(user -> taskContentValidator.validate(command.getContent())
                    .map(correctContent -> new Task(correctContent, command.getPriority(), command.getStatus(), user))
                    .map(task -> user.addTask(task))
                    .map(addedTask -> new TaskDto(addedTask.getId())))
            .getOrElseThrow(() -> new UserNotFoundException(command.getOwnerUsername()));
   }
}
```

Comment: Your question is too vague, it needs additionnal information like all component of your code in action when calling the methode : the user model, the task model, the save method you use, etc.

Comment: I've added a method.

Comment: Try looking at it in a debugger - what does ".map(user -> taskContentValidator.validate(command.getContent())" give you? Looks like you are replacing the original user from the query with your command.getContent() data

Comment: I validate task content from command when user (which will be a task owner) exists. Nothing is replaced.

Comment: So why would .map(addedTask -> new TaskDto(addedTask.getId())  replace the 'addedTask' (the result of the user.addTask(task) call) with a TaskDto, but the call to map(user -> taskContentValidator.validate(command.getContent()) not behave the same?  Check the docs ( https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#map-java.util.function.Function- ) as you confused forEach with map. And it still doesn't make sense to me: taskContentValidator.validate(command.getContent()) should be run once, before the query, not for each 'user' instance returned in the query

Comment: Because .map(user -> taskContentValidator.validate(command.getContent()) doesn't end after command.getContent()) but new TaskDto(addedTask.getId()))). It's nested map. Look exactly on my code.